# How to make buttons to take space and increase size of as much as they want with respect to the resolution?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a layout in which buttons placed on a screen, i want that if the screen has more space then buttons should be three per row, whatever the space they get, also their sizes should be adjusted with screen and i want maximum three buttons per row in the centre of the screen. Right now i have used linear layout for each row of two buttons, please guide me how to make adjustable  buttons so if the screen size is big, it should display three buttons max, if size is very small it should display only two buttons per row with small button sizes and as explained on default screen it should display three buttons per row.

[image]

See my code example here

```
  <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:paddingTop="25dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                <Button
        android:id="@+id/Car"
       android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="110dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="@string/car" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/Taxi"
       android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="110dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="@string/taxi" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: always use wrap_content and match_parent, dont use hardcoded value for width and height.

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar is right. Look at your code, you're setting FIXED dip mesures, so don't expect those buttons to expand on their own. (dp only adapt to different pixels per inch resolutions, not screen sizes).

Comment: what about the linear layout, i want to display three buttons at a time.

Comment: @MuhammadAtifAgha, I am going for today, I can help you tomorrow in details.

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar Please post as an answer, i will accept, just give me a hint, its urgent :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `layout_weight` to set the width of the button automatically according to the width of `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:paddingTop="25dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Car"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="110dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/car" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Taxi"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="110dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/taxi" />
</LinearLayout>
```

However, I don't think you can set the `LinearLayout` to have three buttons depends on the width by XML.  You can only achieve it programmatically.

```
if(getCurrentScreenWidth() > SPECIFIED_WIDTH_FOR_3_BUTTONS){
  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById("wrapper");
  Button button = createNewButton();
  layout.addView(button)
}
```

BUT the best practices will be to load different layout according to screen as described in [android document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this.

For each of your buttons set width like:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Car"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="110dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:text="@string/car" />
```

If you set the width to 0dp and the weight to 1 for each of your buttons then the buttons will expand to fill the space.

Comment: but i dont want to fill more than three buttons per line

Answer (score 0):

Using fix value for height and width may causes the problem with different screen. use below xml code to align button as per your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Car"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/car" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Taxi"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/taxi" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/bus" />

</LinearLayout>
```